# How do i make my player move with a moving platform in unity 2d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm making a 2D platformer and decided to add sticky platforms. I've made the platforms move, but the player doesn't move with them.

However, after parenting the player to the platform, the player still falls through. I have added two `BoxCollider2D`s and set one of them as a `Trigger`. None of the colliders have a `RigidBody2D`

```
public class StickyPlatform : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Player")
            collision.gameObject.transform.SetParent(transform);
    }
    private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Player")
            collision.gameObject.transform.SetParent(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does any of these collider objects have a rigidbody? You need a rigidbody for Triggers to trigger.

Comment: I Tried adding a rigidbody with kinematic properties but it didnt make a difference

Comment: A trigger is _not_ a collider although the same component. Triggers are 'walk and fall throughs', and then it 'triggers' the `OnTrigger*` events while a collider blocks. Has been a while for me using this but the next pushes you into the direction you want to be at least. Remove the trigger (checkbox to false). Then use `OnCollision*`. You need a joint if the character has a `Rigidbody`. Or just parent it to the platform if it has a `CharacterController`.

Answer (score 0):

trigger does not stop object move through the box, you can try OnCollisionEnter.
Usually I would have a ground check and you can say `if(isGrounded&&onPlatform) //move with platform`

Comment: For some reason even when i tried that it still doesnt work???

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds you have two problems:

1. Player is falling through platform
2. Player isn't sticking to the platform

Falling through the floor is a super common bug, with many causes. Here is a [checklist](https://answers.unity.com/questions/147687/checklist-object-or-character-is-falling-through-t.htmlhttps://answers.unity.com/questions/147687/checklist-object-or-character-is-falling-through-t.html) I found:

> 1. does Object have a Collider? If not, select Object
> 2. go to the top bar
> 3. components
> 4. physics
> 5. choose appropriate collider
>    (if Terrain, check the last tab, the little cog-wheel)

> Note: mesh-collider may cause problems
> Particularly, if both FallingObject and GroundObject have mesh-collider
> Particularly, if the mesh is animated
> To avoid mesh-collider, you can build an aproximate shape of your mesh from
> several primitive colliders (in parent-, child- or sibling-GameObjects)
> If you need a Mesh-collider no matter what, you can try to place additional primitive colliders where they won't be in the way to 'enforce' the collisions

> Is the Object a Trigger? If so, select Object
>
> 1. find its Collider-Component (if Terrain, check the last tab, the little cog-wheel)
> 2. remove the check of 'IsTrigger'

> Is the Collider placed well?
> Fiddle with center, size and skin-width (start with 0.1) until the green outline aproximately fits the character
> (If you get really strange values, it might be due to scale (e.g. your mesh was way too big so you downsized to .01))

> You may try to zero out all positioning (both unity and your modeling-program)

The link goes into even more cases.

Once the player can stay on, the physics engine should handle the momentum transfer to move the player with the platform using friction. Which again, requires `RigidBody2D`. I'm not sure why you're not using `RigidBody`s, it kind of feels like you're avoiding the solution.

Doing it this way should avoid the need to parent the player, and have a trigger volume as well, unless you want the player physically stuck and can't move on the platform.